# confusing behavior of instanceof operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

Take a look at this code:

```
function Foo () {
    console.log(this instanceof Foo);
    return { name: "nitesh" }; 
}

foo = new Foo(); //true 
console.log(foo instanceof Foo) //false
```

1. Why is `foo` not an instance of `Foo`?
2. Why is `this` an instance of `Foo`?

Comment: You are basically doing `{ name: "nitesh" } instanceof Foo`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `Foo` function, you are returning an object.  This is what `foo` gets set to.  That is not a `Foo` object, it's just a "normal" object.

Try it this way:

```
function Foo(){
    console.log(this instanceof Foo);
    this.name = "nitesh";
}

var foo = new Foo(); //true 
console.log(foo instanceof Foo) //true
```

Comment: thanks for explanation yet i am still confused how come is this an instance of Foo?

Comment: @niteshsharma: That's how `new` works.  From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new): `The constructor function is called with the specified arguments and 'this' bound to the newly created object.`